# how to write the code to show and hide the data in if condition with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, javascript-objects

In my angular application I have created the dashboard page In that created the map and right side placed the data to display something about the map (i.e created the circle in the map of 5km radius if the marker inside the circle show the details of the marker).

I have written the if loop for the marker comes inside the circle it should be turned to red otherwise blue.

**In that condition I have to show exactly when the drone inside the circle I have to show some data in html. If outside the data should be hidden.**

**component.ts**

```
function inQuadrant(quadrant,marker){
    var inPolygon02 = isMarkerInsidePolygon02(marker,quadrant);
  if(inPolygon){
    quadrant.setStyle({color: 'red'});
  }else{
    quadrant.setStyle({color: '#3388ff'});
  }
}
```

from the above code I have to show the data if it is red color(inside of circle)otherwise hide the data.

**component.html**

```
<div class="tab-pane fade " id="Drones">
  <ul class="list-group card"  id="dd">
    <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let x of datas">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-sm-3" >
          <div class="card-body">
  <img src="{{drone01.iconref}}" width="90" height="90">
  
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I have tried multiple ways but not working properly can anyone help me regarding this.

Comment: `ngIf` You can use. You can create add extra property which you can use in **inQuadrant** function

Comment: I have tried but not working properly,Can you please hard-code the above.

Comment: Where you care calling inQuadrant function

Comment: this.inQuadrant(this.Quadrant1); //this.droneMarker
      this.inQuadrant(this.Quadrant2);
      this.inQuadrant(this.Quadrant3);
      this.inQuadrant(this.Quadrant4);

      this.latlngIdx++;

      this.timeout = setTimeout(()=>{this.nextLatLng()}, this.TIME);